# A Rewrite Rule to remove directory by position, not name

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'd like to have the URL

```
www.example.com/dir1/dir2/current-file.html
```

...point to...

```
www.example.com/dir1/current-file.html
```

...where...

`current-file.html` and `dir2` are variable.  (`dir1` is not variable)

Is this possible with an htaccess file?

**EDIT**

Currently I have:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ ../dir1/current-file.html
```

But this has the file hard coded and assumes `current-file` is in `dir2`. I'd rather target `dir2` by position in the URL if possible.

Comment: Moved what I have into the question .. thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} dir1/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?   [NC]
RewriteRule .* dir1/%1    [R=301,L,QSA]
```

It will redirect permanently:

`http:www.example.com/dir1/anyfolder/anyfile`

To:

`http:www.example.com/dir1/anyfile`

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^dir1/[^/]/(.+)\.html /dir1/$1.html
```

Comment: I see where you are going.. currently it is generating a 404. I'll do a little digging on it.

Comment: Best approach would be to enable the rewrite logging and look up what the URL is actually rewritten to.